# Asking Siri what is the weather

Tags: siri, homepod

I use a Homepod on iOS 14.7 (and 14.6) I say

"hey Siri what is the weather"

Siri pauses and then replies "You need to continue on the companion device"

I go to the device an Iphone SE and see notification which I touch and the phones shows a message "I don't see an app for that" (Difficult to test as I have turned siri off on the phone as it is random whether the phone or Homepod responds)

When I go to the phone to ask Siri I get the same message with a bit more "I don't see an app for that. You'll need to download one." (Difficult to test as I have turned siri off on the phone as it is random whether the phone or Homepod )responds). I have several weather apps

How do I get Siri to tell me the weather? It has worked in the past and I have not deleted any weather apps from my iPhone

I have also asked Siri on the iPhone and I get the same message whether I start Siri by voice or pressing on the Home button

Comment: That works on my HomePod. Maybe it’s not aware of your location for some reason. Does it work on your iPhone?

Comment: In the home app, in your HomePod’s settings, do you have location services enabled? Update: toggling this off just makes Siri ask “weather for where”. What if you ask HomePod for the weather in a specific city?

Comment: Did you update HomePod to latest? I’m going to update mine + iOS and see if I can repro.

Comment: Yes Homepod is now 14.7

Comment: Updated, still works. I'm suspicious of your multiple weather apps. Can you confirm that you didn't set up a shortcut (check on iPhone) so that weather routes to one of your apps? Btw regarding turning Siri off on iPhone - my HomePod mini's and iPhone are pretty good at prioritizing homepod even if I'm closer to my iPhone - but the iPhone should be locked. Also for debugging purposes I'd consider turning Siri on in your iPhone just to see what we get when we ask it for weather.

Comment: I did have a weather shortcut for DarkSky which did work all on Homepod.  but after I had this issue I deleted all weather shortcuts for the reason you gave. ALso turned Siri on - phone 2 inches from mouth, homepod 2 rooms away replied. Repeated 6 inches away phone answered

Comment: Reinstalled Apple's weather apple still same issue.

Comment: Yea I guess when iPhone is locked, it prioritizes HomePod - which I like. Try unlocking your phone first, or even just activate siri manually (holding power button/home button).

Comment: No that is with iPhone unlocked - I can stay still say the command twice in succession and get different devices (also when I had the phone locked) anyway that is not the question here, just shows that there needs to be some way of debugging Siri

Comment: Can you try manually activating Siri on your iPhone to test this?